# Comparing index values within a series

Tags: python

I am creating a new column that will loop through another column. It will take an index from a different column and compare it with the index right before it in the same column and return 1 if the taken index is bigger than its predecessor and 0 if it's smaller.

```
def myfunc(self):
    if df2['US'].iloc[1:].all() > df2['US'].iloc[0:].all():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I was expecting this function to compare each individual index with the one that comes before it, but I think it checks if the sum of the range of indices [1:] is bigger than the sum of indices in range [0:]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare each adjacent item pair, you have to do it explicitly:

```
for i in range(len(df2['US'].iloc) - 1):
    if df2['US'].iloc[i + 1] <= df2['US'].iloc[i]:
        return False
return True
```

That is of course a longer solution if you know about list comprehensions, which could shorten it a bit:

```
return all([df2['US'].iloc[i + 1] <= df2['US'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(df2['US'].iloc) - 1)])
```

Comment: I got an error message saying: object of type '_iLocIndexer' has no len()

I removed the range(len()) from your code and got this:

def myfunc(self):
    for i in df2['US']:
        if df2['US'].iloc[i+1] > df2['US'].iloc[i]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

Does it look okay to you? I am still getting another error saying: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Thanks in Advance!